# Access denied when pushing docker image to gitlab's (on prem) integrated docker registry

Tags: gitlab, docker-registry

When pushing a docker image with a modified tag (to contain registry) to the gitlab integrated registry i get an access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Using the gitlab registry is using it per project. Once the registry is enabled for a project there is a hint how to push the images to the registry `https://gitlab.mydomain.com/**path/to/project**/container_registry`.

The problem got solved when the full path was included in the TAG Name.

When i changed the tagname to [registryUrl]:[registryPort]/**path/to/project**/[imageNameWithTags] i was able to push to the repository/registry.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need to do `docker login ...` as described on the `/container_registry` page.

You can also rely on some [GitLab Predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) to make code generic and re-use it in many projects.

Here is the example of doing it in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
build-image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
```

See full example in [one of our projects](https://gitlab.com/softmill/agents/coreos/blob/23b01dcfc9de0859ec0109f699ecca904f379a95/.gitlab-ci.yml#L20)

Comment: I know and I did login but what I didn‘t notice was that i have to push the image to a specific place since there is no generic all in one space in Gitlab.

Comment: Yes, you are pushing exact image name with tag, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/